# Creating future entries in Firestore

Tags: performance, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have no clue where to post this question, so here it goes.

I have a Vue.js application which lets me order milk for a customer. The customer can choose to order milk either 1, 2, or 7 times a week as a part of a subscription service(90 days, for example).

Based on these number of days(once a week, twice, or 7 times a week), I need to create future orders. But the problem arises in the way I am trying to address this problem.

Should I create future orders beforehand? But if I do so, and if the customer wants milk 3 times a week for 90 days, I would have to create 3*90=270 future records in my firestore subcollection. And that is just for one customer. Is this wise(I know it isn't but I can't put a finger on a solution)?

Also, the user will have a date-time picker where in they can choose a date in the future and get a list of all the orders on that future date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing each recurrence, you could only store the recurrence pattern and then calculate the occurrences on the fly.

This of course does require more calculations, but it saves on the amount of data stored. In that sense this is a classical space vs time tradeoff.

Comment: Hi, just edited my question which missed out a key information. The user will want to select a date from a date picker to see the orders on that day. How should I approach this ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but that was what I had assumed already. You have two basic approaches: either you store all upcoming instances for the coming time period, or you calculate them on the fly as needed.

Comment: Hmm. I think I'll just store them for now. I'm restricting 90 future orders to be created at an instance for now. So I guess it should be fine. But there's another roadblock which I'm trying to get around. I've made an "orders" subcollection in the "customer" collection, reading which isn't straight forward. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's nothing special about reading a subcollection, except that you need to build the `CollectionReference` for the entire path. If you're having a hard time getting that to work, open a new question with the [minimum code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).